# Why are those names of variables problematic?

Tags: variables, scope, sage

If I call L in the following program I get error messages back (TypeError: 'sage.rings.integer.Integer' object is not callable).

```
def N(N,a,b,c):
    return ...

def L(N,a,b,c):
    print N(N,a,b,c)
```

If I change the definition of L to

```
def L(z,a,b,c):
    print N(z,a,b,c)
```

I don't have problems anymore. Can somebody explain why I can't call the first variable N?

Comment: The answer is good, but keep in mind also that in Sage `N()` is predefined as numerical approximation, which trips some people up with the name game as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the compiler thinks `N (..)` is the argument `N` you passed to the function `L`.
Don't forget you can pass functions as arguments to other functions.

In your case, the `N` that was passed was an integer, and when the compiler tried running `N (..)` (aka calling it, hence your error) it broke, since you can't do that to numbers.

Hope that helps.